# Reverse theorem numbering in beamer

Tags: beamer, numbering

In LaTeX beamer I want to number the theorems, and I used the usepackage `\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]`, but I want a reverse numbering that 1.1. Theorem., 1.2. Definition etc., not Theorem 1.1. Could someone help me how can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use the beamer template *theorem begin*. See pp. 124 of beameruserguide.pdf.
The following example is working properly.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
\begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
{%
\inserttheoremheadfont
\thetheorem.
\inserttheoremname
\inserttheorempunctuation
}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{theorem}
         The number 2 is a prime.
    \end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```